# Having trouble presenting an error free screen with Multiple SelectOneMenu drop-downs that are dependent on the previous choice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectonemenu, omnifaces

Newby here.  Would appreciate some direction or assistance.  Thanks in advance.

If the user clicks the Submit button before all choices have been made the screen error's with a NullPointerException.

HTML

```
            <p:panel header="Wip-Emails Employee Assignment List">
            <p:panelGrid id="pg1" columns="4" styleClass="veaGrid: semialert"
                cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputText value="WIP Departments:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width:300px" value="#{wipe.wipDepartments}"
                    var="dpt" id="wipDpt" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a Department" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1st - Select a Department" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{wipe.wipdepartments}" var="dpts"
                        itemLabel="#{dpts.chf_dept_cd} - #{dpts.chf_dept_des}"
                        itemValue="#{dpts}" />
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{dpt.chf_dept_cd}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{dpt.chf_dept_des}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <f:ajax listener="#{wipe.loadEmployeeList}" render="wipUsr" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Department Employees:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width:300px" value="#{wipe.wipUsers}" 
                    var="usr" id="wipUsr" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please select an Employee">

                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2nd - Select an Employee" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{wipe.wipusers}" var="usr"
                        itemLabel="#{usr.sec_usr_id} - #{usr.cicl_lng_nm}"
                        itemValue="#{usr}" />
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{usr.sec_usr_id}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{usr.cicl_lng_nm}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <f:ajax listener="#{wipe.loadSystemGroupCodes}" render="wipGrp" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="System Groups:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width:300px" value="#{wipe.wipGroup}"
                    var="grp" id="wipGrp" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a System Code">

                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3rd - Select a System Code" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{wipe.wipgroups}" var="grp"
                        itemLabel="#{grp.ctc_tag_cd} - #{grp.tag_grp_cd}"
                        itemValue="#{grp}" />
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{grp.ctc_tag_cd}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{grp.tag_grp_cd}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <f:ajax listener="#{wipe.loadwipActivityIDs}" render="wipacy" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Activity Reference IDs" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width:300px" value="#{wipe.wipActivityId}"
                    var="acy" id="wipacy" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a Reference ID">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="4th - Select a Reference ID" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{wipe.wipactivityids}" var="acy"
                        itemLabel="#{acy.acy_id} - #{acy.acy_txt}" itemValue="#{acy}" />
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{acy.acy_id}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{acy.acy_txt}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="ADD" 
                             action="#{wipe.addEmailAssignment}"
                             update=":form1:messages" 
                             process="pg1"
                             icon="ui-icon-check" />
        </p:panel>
```

Bean

```
private ArrayList<WipDepartments> wipdepartments;
private WipDepartments wipDepartments;
private ArrayList<WipUsers> wipusers;
private WipUsers wipUsers;
private ArrayList<WipGroups> wipgroups;
private WipGroups wipGroup;
private ArrayList<WipActivityID> wipactivityids;
private WipActivityID wipActivityId;
private String wipGroupID;
private String userID;
private String activityID;
private String clientID;
private String deptId;
--
    public void loadEmployeeList(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    WipDepartments wipDept = wipDepartments;

    setWipusers(BillingUtilsDAO.getWipUsers(wipDept.getChf_dept_id()));
}
public void loadSystemGroupCodes(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    setWipgroups(BillingUtilsDAO.getWipGroups());
}
public void loadwipActivityIDs(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    WipGroups wipgrp = wipGroup;
    setWipactivityids(BillingUtilsDAO.getWipActivityID(wipgrp.getTag_grp_cd(), wipgrp.getCtc_tag_cd()));

}
```

Comment: After posting this question, it was suggested to me that I might not have the latest version of omnifaces.  After upgrading to 1.13 the problem was corrected.

Comment: Next time you get an exception, by all means include the stack trace in the question. It represents the answer in its entirety.